# Is there a way to always open Google Drive shortcuts from the same account?

Tags: google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-drive

I have 3 accounts attached to my Galaxy S6. I have a Google Drive shortcut to a spreadsheet on my home screen, but every time I click it, a popup asks me which account I want to view it from. The sheet is only shared with one of my accounts.

Is there any way to set a default account to a document? My goal is to reach the sheet in 1 click, and the shortcut currently requires 2, which is the same as if I opened it directly through the Drive app. This defeats the purpose of having a shortcut at all.

Alternatively: If I sync the file to my phone for offline storage, is there a way to create a shortcut widget there directly?

Comment: If you sync for off line access, you can easily create a shortcut using file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). You would need to long press the file in the explorer view and select *more >Add to desktop*. If this is good enough for you can post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the shortcut and re-creating it. When you create a shortcut it should ask you which account to use before you select which file the shortcut should point to.

I had a similar issue on my LG G4 where it always asked which account to use. I think it is because I created the shortcut using a Google account that I subsequently removed and then added back on to the device.